# How to append to a list from multiple list in r?

Tags: r, list, append

I have 4 lists: 3 equally sized filled lists and 1 empty list, for example:

```
list1<-as.list(c(1:10))
list2<-as.list(c(101:110))
list3<-as.list(c(1001:1010))
list4<-list()
```

I want to append the ith element of each of the first 3 lists into the 4th list.
list 4 should look like:

```
[1,101,1001,2,102,1002,....,10,110,1010]
```

How do i go about doing this?
My code currently looks like this:

```
for (i in length(list1)){
  local({
    i<-i
    list4.append(list1[i])
    list4.append(list2[i])
    list4.append(list3[i])

  })
}
```

but i receive the error:

```
could not find function "list4.append"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapply` to combine multiple lists into one. The function used within `mapply` is `c`

```
list4 <- mapply(c, list1, list2, list3, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

**Sample data:**

```
list1 <- as.list(c(1:10))
list2 <- as.list(c(101:110))
list3 <- as.list(c(1001:1010))
```

Comment: @BharatDesai - `c` is the function to apply (FUN).

Answer (score 1):

Using the approach you have on a for-loop, it need some adjustement.

```r
list1<-as.list(c(1:10))
list2<-as.list(c(101:110))
list3<-as.list(c(1001:1010))
list4<-list()

for (i in seq_along(list1)){
    list4 <<- append(list4, list1[i])
    list4 <<- append(list4, list2[i])
    list4 <<- append(list4, list3[i])
}
```

- Don't use `local`, otherwise you won't be able to modify `list4`
- use `<<-` to assign to `list4` outside the for loop
- `append` is a function you assign on an object. It can't be called python-like as a method of the object `obj.method`

Whereas For-loop are what we can be used to, in R it is better to avoid them when possible.

---

Another solution is to use the `purrr` package that helps dealing with list and functional programming. You could get you results with

```r
library(purrr)
pmap(list(list1, list2, list3), c) %>% simplify()
#>  [1]    1  101 1001    2  102 1002    3  103 1003    4  104 1004    5  105
#> [15] 1005    6  106 1006    7  107 1007    8  108 1008    9  109 1009   10
#> [29]  110 1010
```

`pmap` applies a function to each element of the lists in order. (1rst of list1, list2 and list3, then 2nd of list1, list2, list3, ...)
`simplify` is here to get a vector at the end, _simplifying the list result.